# How to compare the value for each row under each columns between two data frames?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Dataframe and I want to compare the value for each rows under each columns.

I could have used the below codes which worked but it is not efficient since in the real work situation, I have more than 50 columns and 95k rows in each dataframe.

Both dataframe has the same number of rows and column names are exactly the same. What is the more efficient way to do it?

This is how the data frame would look like -

**Df1**

Item    Amount  Location
Item1   300 East
Item2   500 West

**Df2**

Item    Amount  Location
Item1   350 East
Item2   500 West

**Desired result**

Item  amount  location  Item2  amount2  location2  amount_diff  Item_diff  location_diff

Item1   300 East    Item1   350 East    False   True    True

Item2   500 West    Item2   500 West    True    True    True

```
first = {'Item': ['Item1','Item2'],
               'amount': [300,500],'location':['East','West']
               }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(first,columns= ['Item', 'amount','location'])

second = {'Item': ['Item1','Item2'],
               'amount': [350,500],'location':['East','West']
               }
df2 = pd.DataFrame(second,columns= ['Item', 'amount','location'])

df1['Item2'] = df2['Item']
df1['amount2'] =df2['amount']
df1['location2'] =df2['location']

df1['Item_diff'] = np.where(df1['Item'] == df1['Item2'], 'True', 'False')
df1['amount_diff'] = np.where(df1['amount'] == df1['amount2'], 'True', 'False')
df1['location_diff'] = np.where(df1['location'] == df1['location2'], 'True', 'False')

df1['Item_diff'] 
df1['amount_diff']
df1['location_diff']
```

Comment: `df1.eq(df2)`????

Comment: the whole thing could be done with 2 `join` like  `df1.join(df2, lsuffix='1', rsuffix='2').join(df1.eq(df2).add_suffix('_diff'))`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works amazingly well. However I still have a question, it seems if both field1 and filed2 are null, field_diff would return Fasle. Do you happen to know why?

Comment: @user032020 it is a convention on [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Comparison_with_NaN), try np.nan==np.nan and you'll get False

Comment: Compare how? Don't use `np.where()` like that, it's unidiomatic. Have you not read the Pandas docs?